# What's the best way of getting the results of GetLastError() after a WinAPI call into a nice char*?

Tags: java, windows, winapi, java-native-interface

I'm writing a DLL which a java program uses to call the WinAPI in various ways.  I want to throw proper exceptions back to java but I need a nicely formated WinAPI error not just the int that get's returned from GetLastError().  I'm sure there's a nice way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use "FormatMessage"; you can pass in the error code as the 3rd parameter, and even have FormatMessage allocate the space for you.

Comment: Yup. That's how I do it. There's some example code here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/formatmessage.aspx